# How can I create a Python dictionary with multiple values for one key from a list, to then create a pandas dataframe with one column and multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas

    in_stock = pandas.read_csv("instock.csv")
    new_data = pandas.read_csv("new_data.csv")
    in_stock_list = in_stock.asset_tag.to_list()

    new_data_list = new_data.asset_tag.to_list()

    missing_list = [items for items in in_stock_list if items not 
    in new_data_list]

    bad_status_list = [items for items in new_data_list if items 
    not in in_stock_list]

    results = {
        "Missing Assets": [missing_list],
        "Wrong Status": [bad_status_list]
    }
```

This creates a single row with all the values in there instead of multiple rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide a snippet of the CSV files you are using. Based on what I see, the missing_list and bad_status_list should contain values within lists. I'm not sure why you would want to put them inside another list, but maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do here.

Remove the brackets within your results dictionary and see if that resolves your issue.

```
results = {
        "Missing Assets": missing_list,
        "Wrong Status": bad_status_list
    }
```

Comment: CSV File
        Column asset_tag
        row1     dummydata
        row2     dummydata

        CSV file2
        Column asset_tag
        row1     dummydata
        row2     dummydata

        **Missing code**

        new_data = pandas.DataFrame(results)
        new_data.to_csv("results.csv")

        I found the answer, when using the lists without brackets it errors out saying list length                 
        mismatch, but I can build it with just one column from one list just fine. In order to do 
        what I wanted I need to use a whole different